# Formulas or VBA - Find String and certain number of characters after it

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I have been using

```
=if(isnumber(search("MyString",A1,1)),"MyString","Not Found")
```

to see if "MyString" exists in a cell with a long description. Usually "MyString" is followed by a number (that changes), like "MyString#".

However, "MyString" and it's number dont always exist in the same spot of the description:

```
A2 = "MyString# is great today."
A3 = "Today is a great day for MyString# to be in Excel."
```

Is there a way I can search for MyString, and then print it and the number that follows it? (I am probably overthinking this or overlooking something simple!)

Thank you!!

Comment: What could be that number? A single digit or multiple digits number and is there any space between MyString and that number? Can you provide few real examples of that?

Comment: Hi Sktneer, a few examples would be "MyString2" "MyString35" "MyString 6" "MyString 72" ... basically a one or two digit number after MyString, sometimes with a space between, other times, without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("MyString",A1),LEN("MyString")+1),"Not Found")`

If you want to display only the number, do this:

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("MyString",A1)+LEN("MyString"),1),"Not Found")`

Note: I assumed that the number followed after "MyString" is always 1 digit.

If the data after MyString# will always be a blank, you can get the number no matter how many digits it is by using the formula below.

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("MyString",A1),SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH("MyString",A1))-SEARCH("MyString",A1)),"Not Found")`

For number only:

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("MyString",A1)+LEN("MyString"),SEARCH(" ",A1,SEARCH("MyString",A1))-SEARCH("MyString",A1)-LEN("MyString")),"Not Found")`